# Mostrar área del círculo, perímetro del rectángulo y volumen del cubo

Tags: c++

El programa debe mostrar el área de un círculo, regresar el perímetro de un rectángulo, calcular el volumen y mostrarlo a través de una función.

El problema es que me está ignorando el calculo. ¿Cómo lo resuelvo?

Código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void areacirculo(float);

float perimetro(float,float );

float volumenCubo(float);

int main()
{

    char nombre;
    int opc,P;
    float radio;
    float medidaradio;
    float lado1,lado2;
    float lado;
    float volumen;
    do{
        cout<<"SELECCIONE LA OPCION DESEADA ";
        cout<<"\n1) Calcular  y mostrar el área de un circulo "
        <<"\n2) Calcular y regresar el perímetro de un rectángulo "
        <<"\n3) Calcular y regresar el volumen de un cubo "
        <<"\n4) Mostrar un saludo "
        <<"\n5) Salir "<<endl;
        cin>>opc;
        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                cout<<"Ingrese radio ";
                cin>>radio;
                medidaradio=areacirculo;
                cout<<"Area del circulo= "<<medidaradio<<endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"Ingrese medida de lados ";
                cin>>lado1>>lado2;
                P= float perimetro;
                cout<<"Perimetro: "<<P<<endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout<<"Ingrese medida del lado ";
                cin>>lado;
                volumen=float volumenCubo;
                cout<<"Volumen= "<<volumen<<endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                cout<<"Ingrese nombre ";
                cin>>nombre;
                cout<<"Hola "<<nombre<<endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                break;      
        }
    }while(opc!=5);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void areacirculo(double){

    float radio,medidaradio;

    medidaradio=3.1416*(radio*radio);

}

float perimetro(float ,float ){

    float P,lado1,lado2;

    P=2*(lado1+lado2);

    return P;

}

float volumenCubo(float ){

    float volumen,lado;

    volumen=(lado*lado*lado);

    return volumen;

}
```

Comment: Zero, estas mezclando variables locales con globales. También estas llamando a funciones que son procedimientos.

Comment: Gracias, la verdad es que no notaba el error en el código, ya que en la consola solo me mostraba 1 o 0,gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 1):

por lo que veo tus métodos reciben parámetros pero a la hora de llamarlos 
no le estas pasando los parámetros.

Ademas veo que tus métodos crean nuevas variables adentro del cuerpo del mismo y no utilizan las que se le paso por parámetro.

Eso no compila por que cuando llamas a los métodos no le estas pasando los parámetros.
Te paso el código arreglado:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

double areaCirculo(double radio) {
    return  3.1416 * (radio * radio);
}

float perimetroRectangulo(float lado1,float lado2) {
    return 2 * (lado1 + lado2);
}

float volumenCubo(float lado) {
    return (lado * lado * lado);
}

int main()
{

    char nombre;
    int opc, P;
    float radio;
    float medidaradio;
    float lado1, lado2;
    float lado;
    float volumen;
    do {
        cout << "SELECCIONE LA OPCION DESEADA ";
        cout << "\n1) Calcular  y mostrar el área de un circulo "
            << "\n2) Calcular y regresar el perímetro de un rectángulo "
            << "\n3) Calcular y regresar el volumen de un cubo "
            << "\n4) Mostrar un saludo "
            << "\n5) Salir " << endl;
        cin >> opc;
        switch (opc) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Ingrese radio ";
            cin >> radio;
            cout << "Area del circulo= " << areaCirculo(radio) << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Ingrese medida de lados ";
            cin >> lado1 >> lado2;
            cout << "Perimetro: " << perimetroRectangulo(lado1,lado2) << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Ingrese medida del lado ";
            cin >> lado;
            cout << "Volumen = " << volumenCubo(lado) << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Ingrese nombre ";
            cin >> nombre;
            cout << "Hola " << nombre << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        }
    } while (opc != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Le quite lo de getch() por que no sabia que era.

Hay un par de cosas de prolijidad de código a tener en cuenta como hacer el .h para la cabecera delas funciones y mas pero no importa luego lo aprenderás.

Ese código te debería funcionar, espero que te haya servido,saludos.

Abrazo

Comment: Gracias, estaba buscando algunas maneras pero no lograba entenderlo, nuevamente gracias

Answer (score 1):

> El problema es que me está ignorando el calculo.

Hay un refrán en el mundo de la programación que dice "[*Select isn't broken*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)", el refrán viene de la siguiente anécdota:

> Trabajamos en un proyecto en que **un ingeniero veterano estaba convencido que el comando *select* del sistema Solaris estaba roto**. Ninguna cantidad de persuasión o lógica le hacía cambiar de idea (el hecho de que cualquier otra aplicación funcionara bien era irrelevante). Pasó semanas escribiendo parches, los cuales, por alguna extraña razón, no parecían resolver el problema. Cuando finalmente fue forzado a sentarse a leer la documentación de *select*, descubrió el problema y lo resolvió en cuestión de minutos. Ahora usamos la frase "*select* no está roto" como un amable recordatorio de  cuando alguien empieza a culpar al sistema de algo que probablemente sea culpa suya.

---

El problema no es que esté ignorando el cálculo, el cálculo está bien, tu código está mal. MUY MAL.

- En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) las funciones pueden recibir parámetros anónimos:

  ```
  void anonimo(int) { std::cout << "No se cómo se llama el parámetro"; }
  void con_nombre(int parametro) { std::cout << parámetro; }
  ```

  La función `anonimo` recibe un parámetro anónimo de tipo `int`, al ser anónimo no puede ser usado. La función `con_nombre` recibe un parámetro de nombre `parametro` y puede usarlo sin problemas.
- En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) las funciones pueden devolver valores o no devolver nada:

  ```
  float devuelvo_algo() { return 42f; }
  void devuelvo_nada() {};
  ```

  Para devolver un valor debes usar la instrucción `return` como se ve en la función `devuelvo_algo`.
- En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) para llamar a una función debes escribir su nombre, y enviar entre paréntesis los argumentos:

  ```
  anonimo(5);
  con_nombre(5);
  ```

En resumen:

1. Tus funciones no usan sus parámetros.
2. Las funciones que deberían devolver valores, no los están devolviendo.
3. No llamas a las funciones adecuadamente.

Echa un vistazo a la respuesta de [Joaquin Ruiz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/312457/2742) que contiene el código correcto, pero que es mejorable:

1. La cabecera `<conio.h>` no se está usando ergo, no debería incluirse.
2. Las funciones usan intermitentemente `float` o `double` mientras que las variables que se leen de la consola son todas `float` mejor decidirse por un tipo concreto.

   1. Esto también es aplicable a los literales numéricos.
3. Se declaran más variables de las necesarias.
4. `nombre` debe ser una cadena, no un carácter.
5. El ámbito de las variables puede reducirse mucho.
6. Pueden haber menos llamadas al operador `<<` de `std::cout`.
7. El quinto caso del `switch` es innecesario.

Arreglando los detalles anteriores, el código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

float areaCirculo(float radio) {
    return  3.1416f * (radio * radio);
}

float perimetroRectangulo(float lado1,float lado2) {
    return 2.f * (lado1 + lado2);
}

float volumenCubo(float lado) {
    return (lado * lado * lado);
}

int main()
{
    int opc;

    do {
        cout << "SELECCIONE LA OPCION DESEADA"
                "\n1) Calcular  y mostrar el área de un circulo"
                "\n2) Calcular y regresar el perímetro de un rectángulo"
                "\n3) Calcular y regresar el volumen de un cubo"
                "\n4) Mostrar un saludo "
                "\n5) Salir\n";

        cin >> opc;
        switch (opc) {
        case 1:
            float radio;
            cout << "Ingrese radio ";
            cin >> radio;
            cout << "Area del circulo= " << areaCirculo(radio) << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            float lado1, lado2;
            cout << "Ingrese medida de lados ";
            cin >> lado1 >> lado2;
            cout << "Perimetro: " << perimetroRectangulo(lado1,lado2) << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            float lado;
            cout << "Ingrese medida del lado ";
            cin >> lado;
            cout << "Volumen = " << volumenCubo(lado) << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            string nombre;
            cout << "Ingrese nombre ";
            cin >> nombre;
            cout << "Hola " << nombre << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (opc != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRLbtswEN3zFFN1Y/UTVP5kETsGDMdAA6RNUANZZcNIjEOUIg1KahAUPkwO0FP4YO6IQ8WSISWWFqJGj0/z3swwXq@/xorr1W73UepYFYmAiTRZbgVPp2wfw4jUqyljRYZP0DwV2ZrHArI8GTP2oAzPgeOuubRxoUyPIpYn0oTwlwFeVuSF1QCDk2gYnT7AJ@i577gg3JhtKqq1sDIVuTW/RJxjfntKxRMTfdmv@wf0/RPH7GDw2UNqzH@MKlKh58V9nfGAxG1HmtqDOKTOIeVS90JGG8qAWcfoQfmGaAqXV2yKHCYTCJaLq8V8fnn9cwFXM7i@KZdwsVguZhez4BVeXcGdjkKYc4U@cgvwDGlZEFwKBdsX9BiwIoWGmKxuZejXGJ5R1cqKjBjQ2e0/Z62nsejw9sVZ3Eo16KTyVlbpoKOtBMMQfngFCMs4dpSBVuQohCVX0t7pwBvqfJQaplNyuYplTzKPH6GHwbBuOc8ERGcN7lonjhsfXutzqUtNgjAQHKDo72/tn1FNVFWRcwjKeH0c/CBgVOhENXnuEfd73NTQb9NArU8t/Y6UVCQycY1SorMOUTQkftFFeVON4hnJahtNysyP49EiB10ijxWnaEC7xXUQ3frG9YWqHwl0GBwtYdiUQMckaJMi@B0VBOpI/k2G70ZxytxzHJPuxq028PQolXCDAx/OYRT6QfMH3zc85Xa7iEWs7@4B3kM2w7@YTBo2Yv8B)</kbd>.

Comment: Gracias, la verdad es que soy bastante principiante en lo que respecta a la programación, entendía todo hasta que en el curso vi lo de arreglos , de ahí no supe que hacer, de igual forma parece que me exprese mal el problema era que no hacia de forma correcta la llamada a las funciones, nuevamente gracias